# Use current time to compare against an array and show information within that range

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

My problem is displaying 3 hour forecast interval based on current time.
the array contains a list of data with 3 hour interval say the time is 5pm and the api call forecasts 15:00-18:00 is cloudy. i want to compare against the user's time and and date to show user "forecast 3pm-6pm : cloudy " and if its 18:30 as per the api call show "forecast 6:pm - 9pm" and so on....

this is my data/api call

```js
var foreCastCall = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&appid=336a685c326c4e2eb0041535da37b389`;

  function getWeather(callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: foreCastCall,
      success: callback
    });
}
 
  getWeather(function (data) {
  
    for (var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i+=1) {
      
 console.log("time forecast is", data.list[i].dt_txt); //forecast time
      console.log("full data is..", data); //full json response

    }
```

i got this code below to compare time but i am having trouble using the logic for array

```js
      function checkTime() {
        var d = new Date(); // current time
        var hours = d.getHours();
        var mins = d.getMinutes();
        var day = d.getDay();
    
        return day >= 1
             && hours >= 9
             && (hours < 17 || hours === 17 && mins <= 30);
    }
```

Comment: What is data.list[i].dt_txt? Whether using Moment.js (wonderful library) or the native Date(), you'll need to get the array data into a date. To answer your question, understanding what your data looks like will be helpful.

Comment: @CuriousChad i edited the code with my api call. the data.list[i].dt_text is the time intervals between forecast which i want to compare to real time and display the info for that certain time range. any example of how to get data into a date?